# What response code to return for insecure POST not acceptable?

Tags: security, http, redirect, https, post-redirect-get

If somebody accesses my server via http (i. e. not https) then I redirect GET requests to the https version.

But I don't know what to do with POST and PUT because I cannot redirect them (the browser does a GET on redirect I believe).

I should return an error code.  **What HTTP error code should I return?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-18.txt explains HTTP response codes.  If you want an error code, just return a 404 if requests cannot be serviced at that URL.

> 7.4.5.  404 Not Found
>
> The server has not found anything matching the effective request URI.
>      No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or
>      permanent.  The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server
>      knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old
>      resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
>      This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to
>      reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other
>      response is applicable.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i am not sure whether 403 as described in the answer immediately after yours, is better than 404 or not.

Comment: one determinant is whether or not the URL would otherwise be valid (i. e. if sent over https). if i am sure it would be valid i think 403 would be preferable. if it is a filter that indiscriminately filters all insecure posts, then it would not know whether it is a valid URL or not and therefore 404 might be better.

Comment: @agksmehx, 403 is for requests that might be valid if they included different credentials.  That is not the case in your situation.

Comment: Yes, that's what the IETF text also says that 403 is in response to some credentials, so 403 is not clearly more appropriate than 404. Thank you.

Comment: 403 is still a better choice. -> There is a substatus error code for HTTP 403s specifically for this situation. 403.4 is "SSL Required" which is exactly your situation. I don't think there's a specific RFC for this, but both Apache and Microsoft IIS specify this, so it's at least a defacto standard. Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/21079107-1740-470e-a933-23a45494b8ba.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would return a 403 - Forbidden. The general description of this is "The server understood the request, but refuses to authorize it." which would fit your situation.

Comment: thanks, i am inclined to think 403 is better than 404 but i am not sure. i will accept your answer after i am a bit more sure.

Comment: one determinant is whether or not the URL would otherwise be valid (i. e. if sent over https). if i am sure it would be valid i think 403 would be preferable. if it is a filter that indiscriminately filters all insecure posts, then it would not know whether it is a valid URL or not and therefore 404 might be better.

Comment: 403 is still a better choice. -> There is a substatus error code for HTTP 403s specifically for this situation. 403.4 is "SSL Required" which is exactly your situation. I don't think there's a specific RFC for this, but both Apache and Microsoft IIS specify this, so it's at least a defacto standard. Reference: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/21079107-1740-470e-a933-23a45494b8ba.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 1):

Technically right answer is to use 403.4 but substatuses it's a IIS only feature and nginx doesn't support it.

So I've prefer to return 418 "I'm a teapot" or 451 "Unavailable For Legal Reasons" (because it's not legal to use plain-text http anymore, haha, just joking :)), this statuses quite exotic and should trigger client to figure out what going on.

nginx has an option to return status with text like

```
# cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
server {
    listen       80 default_server;


    location / {
        add_header Content-Type text/plain;
        return 418 "TLS REQUIRED";
    }
}

# curl -v  http://localhost/
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 418
< Server: nginx/1.16.1
< Date: Sat, 15 Feb 2020 07:13:20 GMT
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Content-Length: 12
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
TLS REQUIRED
```

But browsers like Chrome or Firefox can't handle this right, Chrome says ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE and Firefox says "File not found" and this behavior doesn't solve our goal.

So I've stay with just returning status 418.